# Oracle NetSuite Integration REST Connection

Tags: oracle, rest, netsuite

I am looking for a place where its explained how to connect to Oracle NetSuite SuiteTalk to pull accounting data ?. I am developing a REST microservices with spring boot and I need to integrate this. Does anyone knows something about this ?. Or how to do the integration ?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [SuiteTalk REST Web Services](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTRW/NSTRW.pdf) - page 11 has Authentication information.

Comment: Thanks you very much !.